# Suppose $T \in \mathcal{L}(V)$. Prove that $T / \text{range} \ T = 0$.

Tags: linear-algebra

Suppose $T \in \mathcal{L}(V)$. Prove that $T / \text{range} \ T = 0$.

I encountered this exercise in Sheldon Axler's Linear Algebra Done Right in the chapter on eigenvalues and invariant subspaces. I don't understand what  $T / \text{range} \ T$ is... I thought that notation meant the quotient space, but $T$ is a linear operator, but that doesn't make much sense to me.

My attempt is to suppose that $x \in T / \text{range} \ T$ and show that $x = 0$, but I am stuck after that.

Comment: The definition of the linear operator $T/U$, where $U$ is a subspace of $V$ that is invariant under $T$, is given on page 137 of Linear Algebra Done Right (3rd edition).

Answer (score 2):

Let $U$ be a $T$-invariant subspace of $V$, i.e. $T(U) \subset U$. The linear map

$$T/U: V/U \to V/U, v+U \mapsto Tv+U$$ is well defined.

$\operatorname{range}T$ is $T$-invariant, hence we can look at

$$T/\operatorname{range}T: V/\operatorname{range}T \to V/\operatorname{range}T, v+\operatorname{range}T \mapsto Tv+\operatorname{range}T$$

and easily show that is is the zero-map, since $Tv \in \operatorname{range}T$ for all $v \in V$. Thus we have $Tv+\operatorname{range}T=0 \in V/\operatorname{range}T$.